# How to remove unused git branches

Tags: git, tortoisegit

How can one remove unused git bracnhes from Tortoise-Git? These branches have been removed both locally and remotely, i'd like to not see them anymore when using this dropdown

[image]

Comment: I think this has been asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19928808/deleted-remote-branches-still-listed-in-tortoisegit and that answer is pretty good.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to run `git remote prune origin`. This will get rid of remote tracking branches which no longer represent a branch on the remote.

Comment: Does not remove it from Tortoise-Git. Is there anything specific i need to do for this application?

Comment: when you run `git branch -a` do you see those branches (with or without origin)?

Comment: Adam - both locally and remotely i see only branches i need to see. Noise that shows up on top is not present

Comment: Are you looking at a different repository possibly? What does .git/refs contain?

Answer (score 22):

As of TortoiseGit 2.4.0.2 there is a way to let it execute `git remote prune origin`. In the Sync window you can select "Clean up stale remote branches" which then will remove all already removed remote branches from your local cache.

I don't know if this already exists in previous versions, because I normally use the command line ^^

Comment: perfect! this is the option on the tortoisegit. no command line required.

Comment: Talking about tortoisegit this is the perfect answer!

Comment: I almost exclusively use the git log view of TortoiseGit, as I can do everything I need to and see the entire state of the repo from this one view. From the fetch dialog there is a "Prune" checkbox as well that if checked appears to do the exact same thing. This answer led me to discover this.

Comment: BTW it's in the "Pull" pull-down menu.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you just pruned/removed the branches and the cache is not up-to-date. You could kill the `tgitcache.exe` process to reset the cache.

Comment: Killing (and later restarting) this process does not reset cached entries

Answer (score 0):

You can do 'view log' and then scroll down to where you see the branch marker, right-click and ask to delete it.  Typically you will see it twice as foo and origin/foo and you may want to delete both.

I have not found a way to do the equivalent of `git remote prune origin` from the TortoiseGit GUI.